# Use UIDocumentInteractionController in Delphi XE

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a Delphi XE5 app which downloads and stores PDFs locally on the device.  I have a TWebBrowser on the form to view the PDFs and it works perfectly.

I now wish to share the PDF with other applications (eg Safari, Mail, etc) but am really struggling!  I have looked at the TShowShareAction action (on the Action List control) but this caters for a Bitmap (photo) to be shared.

I have seen a lot of posts explaining that one should use UIDocumentInteractionController but I cannot find examples of how to use this from within Delphi.  I have looked at Apple.Utils but to no avail.

Has anyone used the UIDocumentInteractionController functionality from within a Delphi application to share a file?  Any example would be much appreciated!

Comment: See my other post which answers this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488564/share-local-file-with-other-apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by installing [D.P.F. Delphi iOS Native Components](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dpfdelphiios/)

I then added a DPFQLPreviewController to my form and open the PDF with the following code:

```
DPFQLPreviewController1.ShowDoc(filename, false);
```

This opens the PDF in the standard iOS previewer and this has a button enabling one to share the file with other installed apps that can read the file (eg a PDF app, email, send to printer, etc)

This is by far the simplest solution I have found and works perfectly on the simulator and an actual device.