# Share local file with other apps

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am using Delphi XE5 for iOS development and would like to share a local file (in my app sandbox) with other applications installed on the device.  I have read up on using Objective C to implement **UIWebView** or **UIDocumentInteractionController** or even **QLPreviewController**, but I cannot find any documentation of using these in Delphi.

The Delphi TActionList does not contain functionality for local files.

I currently display a local PDF in a TWebBrowser, but I would like to share it with a locally installed PDF viewer that I have.

Can anyone assist?