# Open a PDF with Adobe Acrobat Reader in iOS with a Delphi Firemonkey app

Tags: ios, delphi, pdf, firemonkey

I want my FireMonkey iOS app to open a PDF in Adobe Acrobat Reader that it has received by app tethering.

I've tried the Posix `Shell Execute`:

```
_system(MarshaledAString('open ' + 'myFile.pdf'));
```

But it doesn't work (note : I use :`MarshaledAString`, because `PAnsiChar` and `AnsiString` are not available for a mobile compiled application).

It is easily done with Android, but iOS....

Anyone know a way to make this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20352730/62576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like iOS sandboxing makes it impossible for an app like Acrobat Reader to come and read a file belonging to the app I've built.

The farthest I came was to open the PDF file in a TWebBrowser. But the file cannot be edited.

```
     frm := TForm.CreateNew(nil);

     btn := TButton.Create(frm);
     btn.Parent := frm;
     btn.Align := TAlignLayout.Top;
     btn.Text := 'Close';

     btn.OnClick := OnButtonClick;
     WebBrowswer := TWebBrowser.Create(frm);

     WebBrowswer.Parent := frm;
     WebBrowswer.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;

     WebBrowswer.Navigate('file://' + FLastFileReceivedFilePath);
     frm.Show;
```